# For loop charts - changing xtick frequency dynamically for each chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to increase the number of xticks for each chart in the dataframe.

```
for c in df:
   fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10,5]);
   ax = df[c].plot(kind='hist', color=(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.6), bins=30);
```

[image: Chart]

I've tried:

```
ax.xticks(np.arange(min(c),max(x)+1,1));
```

Results in an AttributeError.

Thus are there any methods to increase the number of xticks without specifying the ticks explicitly but rather dynamically so it works for all the charts?

Comment: You can try `ax.set_xticks(...)`. The `.xticks` is of `plt` itself, so alternatively `plt.xticks(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function doesn't understand the c in min (and I guess it is max(c) too.
it works this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10,5])
for c in df:
  ax = df[c].plot(kind='hist', color=(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.6), bins=30)
  plt.xticks(np.arange(min(df[c]),max(df[c]), step = 1))
```